# Uncaught ReferenceError: noty is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, notifications, noty

I faced a problem where the notification could not be displayed with noty plugin. 
I included this plugin in ASP.net web application.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/sticky_footer.css" />
<link href="~/lib/noty/lib/noty.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/noty/lib/noty.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/he/he.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table-contextmenu/dist/bootstrap-table-contextmenu.min.js"></script>
```

Create.cshtml

```
 $updateSessionSynopsisHandler.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            noty({
                text: data.message, type: 'success',
                layout: 'center'
            });

        });
```

The error 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the [Noty document](https://ned.im/noty/#/installation), i think Noty is a constructor function. It should be instantiated before you want use it. Try this

```
$updateSessionSynopsisHandler.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        new Noty({
            text: data.message, type: 'success',
            layout: 'center'
        }).show();
    });
```